# Redefinition of class error when including a header file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi you all.
I'm trying to implement a list of odometry measurements and I defined nodes in .h and .cpp files.
Then, in a client class **Stage_listener.cpp**(having an associated .h file that, I guess, it's not useful to include here), I try to create a node :

```
 
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Point.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "stage_listener.h"
#include "odom_node.h"
//#include "tf/transform_listener.h"

void stage_listener::addOdomNode (const nav_msgs::Odometry mes){
    geometry_msgs::Pose robot_pose = mes.pose.pose;
    geometry_msgs::Point robot_point = robot_pose.position;
    
    //float xCoord = robot_point.x;
    //float yCoord = robot_point.y;
    //float zCoord = robot_point.z;

    odom_node on;
    //on.xCoord = robot_point.x;
    //double orientation = tf::getYaw(robot_pose.orientation);
}

int main(){}
```

Here are the two files I used to define the odometric nodes.
This is the header:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

class odom_node{
public:
    odom_node();
    //~odom_node();
    float xCoord;
    float yCoord;
    float angle;
    std::string frame_id;
};
```

And this is the associated .cpp file:

```
#include "odom_node.h"

odom_node::odom_node(){
}
```

The latter is very simple since there are no functions to be implemented; now I get an error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/stage_listener.dir/src/stage_listener.o
In file included from /home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/src/stage_listener.cpp:8:0:
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/src/odom_node.h:3:7: error: redefinition of ‘class odom_node’
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/src/odom_node.h:3:7: error: previous definition of ‘class odom_node’
```

I can't get rid of it. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your help and sorry for my boring ROS/C++ newbie questions :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48634/redefinition-of-class-error-when-including-a-header-file/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-11-20**:
thanks for your suggestion, Lorenz
sadly, i was given a project and c++ at the same time and expiration date for delivery forces not to dedicate much time to learning deeply c++

anyway, i had added in meanwhile #ifndef etc...
now i get a new error: "undefined reference to `odom_node::odom_node()"

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-11-20**:
the error appears when i write
"odom_node on;" in stage_listener.cpp

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-20**:
The problem now is the same as in your previous question. You are not linking together all your C++ files. I don't think you will be able to solve your assignment until you learn C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably missing the #ifndef guards in your header file. In C++ you need to add:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

... header file contents ...

#endif
```

I really suggest that you dive into C++ a little more before continuing with ROS. A solid knowledge of that language will save you a lot of time.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1